# os.listdir vs grep in a Prefect schedule

Tags: python, grep, listdir, prefect

I'm scheduling tasks with Prefect this way :

```
#Python script
from prefect import task, Flow
from prefect.tasks.shell import ShellTask
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
from prefect.schedules import IntervalSchedule
import os
import sys

schedule = IntervalSchedule(start_date=datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=10),interval=timedelta(minutes=1))
can_start = True

with Flow("List files", schedule) as flow:
    
    if can_start:
        can_start = False
        file_names = os.listdir("/home/admin/data/raw")
        file_names = fnmatch.filter(file_names, "*fact*")
        process_common.map(file_names)
        can_start = True
    
out = flow.run()
```

But if files arrive into my directory *after* the first Prefect run, file_names remain empty during the second run, and also during all the next ones.

I have tried to fetch my files with a grep command, and then it works !

```
file_names = ShellTask(command="ls /home/admin/data/raw | grep fact", return_all=True, log_stderr=True, stream_output=True)
```

Does someone know why that happens ? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? If there are no files when listing files, of course there will not be any files listed.

Comment: there are no files at the first run. Then I put files between run1 and run2. Run2 does not find anything. Is it clearer ? I'll add precisions to my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common confusion point - you are conflating build-time logic with runtime logic (see [this SO post for another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64155793/is-it-possible-to-loop-over-a-prefect-parameter/64158793#64158793)).

All logic that you want to have effect at runtime should be encapsulated as a Prefect task - in your case, you *may* need to use Prefect's [conditional tasks](https://docs.prefect.io/core/idioms/conditional.html) to achieve your outcome, although you might be able to get away with something much simpler.

In particular, the following code seems to have the desired outcome:

```py
@task
def get_filenames():
    file_names = os.listdir("/home/admin/data/raw")
    file_names = fnmatch.filter(file_names, "*fact*")
    return file_names


with Flow("List files", schedule) as flow:
    process_common.map(file_names) # if the list is empty, nothing will happen
    
out = flow.run()
```

Lastly, note that you can effectively mark tasks as "skipped" based on dynamic runtime conditions using [SKIP signals](https://docs.prefect.io/core/concepts/execution.html#state-signals).